# Scrapy command in shell script not executing when called from java

Tags: java, bash, shell, scrapy

I have the below shell script which invokes scrapy

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=usr/local/bin/scrapy:$PATH
scrapy crawl flipkart -a key="$1" -o "$2"flipkart.xml
scrapy crawl myntra -a key="$1" -o "$2"myntra.xml
scrapy crawl jabong -a key="$1" -o "$2"jabong.xml

echo $PATH
```

In the java program which calls this script file the error stream says that          scrapy: command not found

I have the scrapy path added in the bash_profile file and on executing PATH i get the result

```
renny$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin/scrapy:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I am running the script file using the following code

```
String command = "/Users/renny/Documents/WorkSpaces/Scrapy/tutorial/tutorial/crawls.sh";        

String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/sh", command,key,formattedDate};
//Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
Process p2 = p.start();

int code = p2.waitFor();
```

It works fine if i execute the shell script directly.

Comment: What do you get from the `echo $PATH` in the script as executed by java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are missing forward slash on your 'PATH' declaration, and path should be to the directory, not the program

You have

```
export PATH=usr/local/bin/scrapy:$PATH
```

Should be

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: The code snippet is missing the slash but the echo output isn't. Also the echo output indicates that `/usr/local/bin` is already in the `PATH`.

Comment: Output $PATH as a first line in your script, and see in the output stream, what Java thinks it is.

Answer (score 0):

I included

```
cd /Users/renny/Documents/WorkSpaces/Scrapy/tutorial
export PATH=usr/local/bin/scrapy:$PATH
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

and now it seems to be working not sure why but while running the script from java i need to add these to the path through the file but while running the script file directly it does not need these PATH to be written in the file.

Also scrapy seems to need to be in the project directory so added the cd to the project path

Comment: Your shell startup scripts may be modifying the `PATH` in ways that your manual calling of `/bin/sh` (which isn't `/bin/bash` does not).